# Spring MVC static resource being consumed by Java and doesn't allow edition on it

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a restful application where we have separate teams for both the frontend and backend development and right now I am facing some complains from the front developers because they say Java is holding the static resources and doesn't allow them to save any file while the server is running (they run a local Jetty server with the Java app).

What I realize was that if I use the default dispatcher servlet like below this problem disappear:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On the other hand if I use it the way we need it to be, the problem returns:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also have this configured for the static content:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue? I want to be able to have my restful services being dispatched only if prefixed /api.

Thanks.